# Xero API Disconnect Issue ,Not able to see login screen after disconnecting

Tags: c#, xero-api

I am disconnecting with xero as per the xero documentation that is revocation of the connection and deleting the organization which are connected and both the apis are working fine. But when I disconnect and click on connect again it still remembers the previous organization connected and without showing the xero page of organization it redirects me back to my application and I am connected now.

But I want the xero to show its page where I can choose the organization I want. For now I am deleting the XeroIdentity cookie from my browser. Is it a good approach as it shows me the login page now? if not please
do suggest me a way for this.

Here is my code to disconnect

```
  public async Task<JsonResult> RemoveConnection(string token, string Id)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Id == null)
            {
                return Json("Please connect with Xero first");
            }   
       
            else
            {
                var accessToken1 = "";
                var tenantId1 = "";
                var token1 = await _tokenStore.GetAccessTokenAsync(Id);

                accessToken1 = token1.AccessToken;
                var restclient1 = new RestClient("https://identity.xero.com/connect/revocation");
                var request1 = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                string encoded = base64encode(Configuration["xero:clientid"] + ":" + Configuration["xero:clientsecret"]);
                request1.AddHeader("authorization", string.Format("basic {0}", encoded));
                request1.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                request1.AddParameter("application/json",string.Format("token={0}", accessToken1),ParameterType.RequestBody);
                var response1 = restclient1.Execute(request1);
                var connections1 = await _xeroClient.GetConnectionsAsync(token1);
                foreach (var connection in connections1)
                {

                    accessToken1 = token1.AccessToken;
                    tenantId1 = connection.id.ToString();
                    var restClient = new RestClient("https://api.xero.com/connections/" + tenantId1 + "");
                    var request = new RestRequest(Method.DELETE);
                    request.AddHeader("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", accessToken1));
                    var response = restClient.Execute(request);
                    var x = response.Content;
                    var connections12 = await _xeroClient.GetConnectionsAsync(token1);
                }
         
                var details = new { Result = "Disconnected", Status = "Ok" };
                return Json(details);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Heya.  So, the code you have there looks appropriate for disconnecting orgs, as long as you're receiving a 200 response on your DELETE request.  Note, you could also REVOKE the users token, which will delete ALL their orgs, and require them to re-auth against your Xero App.  By deleting the connections/orgs individually, the user will remain authenticated against your app, but you can send them through the flow in order to connect additional orgs.

Comment: Regarding re-auth.  If the user has recently authenticated, cookies are dropped.  So the user will not have to re-enter their username & password each time they auth.  This is normal, and outside of your control.  It shouldn't impact your integration tho.  The only time the user will be forwarded through the auth process & re-directed back to your app is when 1) They already have an auth'd connection with your API App & 2) They do not have any orgs which are NOT already connected to that app.

Comment: So that leads me to believe that a) You're not successfully disconnecting these orgs. and possibly b) you don't have any additional orgs to connect.

Things to try: 1) Check that your DELETE call is actually deleting a connection.  Check the response code, and check in the developer.xero.com portal under "Health" that your connections are dropping (eg: https://developer.xero.com/app/health/32db1579-3ae7-4564-8ef5-b352bf807114)

Comment: 2) Try revoking the entire token (this will disconnect all orgs, and un-auth the user from your app). Maybe this enables the behaviour you're after.

https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/oauth2/auth-flow#revoking-tokens